# Linux Mint 20 suspends whenever I close the lid after connecting and disconnecting an external monitor

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, suspend

On my Linux Mint, I have it set up to "Do nothing" when the lid is closed. This works fine *until* I connect and disconnect an external monitor. Thereafter, the computer goes to sleep everytime the lid is closed no matter what settings I choose.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal option in "Power Management" goes missing after connecting the external monitor so I solved this by installing Tweaks

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Running "Tweaks" from the start menu and setting "Suspend while lid is closed" to False.